# By default outer join is bidiractional?

Tags: database, join

By default outer join is bidirectional ?
or only left join or only right join?

Answer (score 0):

`outer join` is syntactically the same as `left join` or `left outer join`. Some (most?) [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms)s support a `full outer join` syntax which allows missing rows on both sides of the join.